# Conversion from Oracle to ANSI outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, ansi-sql

I have to rewrite a lot of SQL queries with Oracle outer join notation (+) to ANSI SQL. I read something about Oracle syntax but there were very easy examples. How should look this query in ANSI notation?

```
SELECT * FROM realtion r1, relation r2 WHERE r1.relno=r2.relno(+) AND r.id(+)=10
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Mail M, Code C, Relation R WHERE M.STATUS = 2 AND C.id = M.usrID AND r.relo(+) = m.item AND R.item(+) = m.att
```

Comment: The first query seems to be written incorrectly - you have `r.id(+) = 10` but there's no table with an alias of 'r'.

Answer (score 0):

In a first query you have alias r, my guess it is r2.

```
SELECT * FROM realtion r1 
left join relation r2 on r1.relno=r2.relno AND r2.id=10
```

if r2.id is not part of a join:

```
SELECT * FROM realtion r1 
left join relation r2 on r1.relno=r2.relno 
WHERE r2.id=10 or r2.id is null
```

and (my guess m.status is not part of a join)

```
SELECT * FROM Mail M 
inner join Code C on m.usrID = c.id 
left join Relation R on m.item = r.relo and m.att = r.item 
WHERE M.STATUS = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

First query (assuming that by `r.ID` you meant `r2.ID`):

```
SELECT *
  FROM realtion r1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN relation r2 
    ON r2.relno = r1.relno AND
       r2.id = 10
```

Second query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Mail M
  INNER JOIN Code C
    ON C.id = M.usrID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Relation R 
    ON r.relo = m.item AND
       R.item = m.att
  WHERE M.STATUS = 2
```

Share and enjoy.