# oracle grammar to h2 grammar (+) join table

Tags: database, oracle, join, h2

I have the following query as Oracle

```
   SELECT DISTINCT count(pa.payment_id)   FROM
    location c,    inventory e,
    inventory_stock es,    payment_client ep,
    payment pa,    currency cur,
    location s,    exchange_country exc,
    exchange_rate sso,
    exchange_hike so,
    exchange_margin sov  WHERE
    cur.outState = 'N' AND
    c.location_id = e.location_id AND
    e.inventory_id = ep.inventory_id AND
    e.inventory_stock_id = es.inventory_stock_id AND
    ep.client_id = pa.end_client AND
    pa.cur_id = cur.cur_id AND
    cur.location_id = s.location_id AND
    c.client_id  is not null  AND
    cur.cur_id = exc.cur_id(+) AND
    exc.exchange_id = sso.exchange_id(+) AND
    sso.account_id = so.account_id(+) AND
    so.option_name(+)  = 'PREMIUM' AND
    exc.exchange_id = sov.exchange_id(+) AND
    sov.name(+)  = 'VALUE';
```

Right now I am using H2 database and the syntax error I got was from `so.option_name(+)` and `sov.name(+);` I know the (+) are oracle's way of right join and left join but are there any possible way to convert this into h2 so the error and the grammar are equivalent?

Comment: I have tried to converted it using pure join but the output is different. and using join for all the tables are too messy

Comment: Yes you can convert that into a proper `left join` - and you should do that in Oracle as well. Even Oracle recommends to use `left join` (or `right join`) over the proprietary `(+)` operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23762963/330315

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852067/convert-oracle-outer-join-to-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's time to move on. Oracle's legacy outer join syntax is no longer recommended by Oracle. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm):

> Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and restrictions, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax [...]

If you replace `(+)` usage by `outer join`, not only will your query work on both Oracle and H2, it will also be an important step forward for your application as a whole.

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(pa.payment_id) 
FROM location c
JOIN inventory e ON c.location_id = e.location_id
JOIN payment_client ep ON e.inventory_id = ep.inventory_id
JOIN inventory_stock es ON e.inventory_stock_id = es.inventory_stock_id
JOIN payment pa ON ep.client_id = pa.end_client
JOIN currency cur ON pa.cur_id = cur.cur_id
JOIN location s ON cur.location_id = s.location_id
LEFT JOIN exchange_country exc ON cur.cur_id = exc.cur_id
LEFT JOIN exchange_rate sso ON exc.exchange_id = sso.exchange_id
LEFT JOIN exchange_hike so 
  ON sso.account_id = so.account_id
  AND so.option_name = 'PREMIUM'
LEFT JOIN exchange_margin sov 
  ON exc.exchange_id = sov.exchange_id
  AND sov.name = 'VALUE'
WHERE c.client_id IS NOT NULL
AND cur.outState = 'N'
```

The importance when converting from `(+)` to `LEFT JOIN` is that you pay close attention which predicates must go into an `ON` clause, and which predicates are fine in the `WHERE` clause. In particular, the following two predicates must go in the relevant left joined table's `ON` clause:

- `so.option_name(+) = 'PREMIUM'`
- `sov.name(+) = 'VALUE'`

#### Third party tooling

You can use jOOQ's online [SQL translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/) to translate between the syntaxes, or use jOOQ directly to [translate from table lists with Oracle joins to ansi joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/sql-transformation/table-lists-to-ansi-join/).

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/457) suggests that H2 does not support full outer joines, so the statement "your query [will work] on both Oracle and H2" confuses me

Comment: @Felk: My answer does not use full outer join, nor does the `(+)` syntax support it... So, what exactly is your confusion? :)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I didn't notice the "outer join" implicitly meant left outer join

Comment: @Felk: Oh I see what you mean. Indeed, technically, Oracle's documentation is not entirely accurate.